# Multicol, vertical alignment of normal text lines

Tags: multicol, grid-typesetting

Is there an environment like `multicol` that would horizontally align lines of columns?

I was asked to help with a dictionary and the layout should have two columns. Running plain text is fine, lines are aligned. However, the user wants big separator letters, so that there would be a big A, then "aalto - wave", "aika - time" etc, big letter B, then "banaani - banana" etc.

I tried to make a macro, something like

```
\newcommand{\bigletter}[1]{\vspace{1.97\baselineskip}
\scalebox{2}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont \textbf{#1}}
\vspace{1.05\baselineskip}}
```

I was not able to make it work. And in any case, what if there should be pictures of different sizes to put inside the text? So there should be an environment for this, or a macro saying "vertical space until we reach next position where a new line would start if there were just plain text".

Here is an example document. At the end of page two lines are not aligned:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, finnish, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom=0.9in,top=0.9in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{6.0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\bigletter}{\vspace{9.8mm}
{\fontsize{24pt}{0pt}\selectfont \textbf{E}}
\vspace{3mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
  
cumulative sum chart

\bigletter

\textbf{\textit{D}-optimaalisuus} $D$-optimality

\textbf{\textit{d}-separaatio} $d$-separation

\textbf{Dantzig-valitsin} Dantzig selector

\textbf{data} data

\textbf{data-analyysi} data analysis

\textbf{datajoukko} data set

\textbf{datakehikko} data frame

\textbf{datakuutio} data cube

\textbf{datamatriisi} data matrix

\textbf{datan esikäsittely} data pre\-processing

\textbf{datan linkittäminen} data linkage

\textbf{datan ruoppaus} data dredging

\textbf{datan syvyys} data depth

\textbf{datan tiivistäminen} data reduction

\textbf{datan kurkistelu} data peeking

\textbf{datanlouhinta} data mining

\textbf{datan myrkyttäminen} data poisoning

\textbf{datatiede} data science

\textbf{datavetoinen} data driven

\textbf{de facto -väestö} de facto population

\textbf{de jure -väestö} de jure population

\textbf{deflaatio} deflation

\textbf{degeneroitunut jakauma} degenerate distribution

\textbf{dekomponointi} decomposition$_1$

\textbf{dekomponoituva malli} decomposable model

\textbf{dekonvoluutio} deconvolution

\textbf{deltamenetelmä} delta method

\textbf{demografia} demography

\textbf{derivaatta} derivative$_1$

\textbf{derivoituvuus} differentiability

\textbf{desiili} decile

\textbf{determinaatiokerroin} coefficient of determination

\textbf{determinantti} determinant

\textbf{deterministinen} deterministic

\textbf{devianssi} deviance

\textbf{devianssi-informaatiokriteeri} deviance information criterion

\textbf{devianssijäännös} deviance residual

\textbf{diagnostiikka} diagnostics

\textbf{diagnostinen suure} diagnostic sta\-tis\-tic

\textbf{diagnostinen testi} diagnostic test

\textbf{diagonaalimatriisi} diagonal matrix

\textbf{diagrammi} diagram

\textbf{differenssiyhtälö} difference equa\-tion

\textbf{differensointi} differencing

\textbf{differentiaaliyhtälö} differential equa\-tion

\textbf{differentioituvuus} differentiability

\textbf{differointi} differencing

\textbf{diffuusi priori} diffuse prior

\textbf{diffuusioindeksi} diffusion index

\textbf{diffuusioprosessi} diffusion process

\textbf{digammafunktio} digamma function

\textbf{dikotomia} dichotomy

\textbf{dikotominen muuttuja} dichotomous variable, binary variable

\textbf{dimensiokirous} curse of dimensionality

\textbf{dimension pienennys} dimension reduction

\textbf{Diracin deltafunktio} Dirac's delta function

\textbf{Diracin mitta} Dirac measure

\textbf{Dirichlet-jakauma} Dirichlet distribution

\textbf{Dirichlet-prosessi} Dirichlet process

\textbf{diskonttaus} discounting

\textbf{diskordanssi} discordance

\textbf{diskordantit parit} discordant pairs

\textbf{diskreetti} discrete

\textbf{diskreetti jakauma} discrete distribution

\textbf{diskreetti muuttuja} discrete variable

\textbf{diskreettiaikainen} discrete-time

\textbf{diskriminantti} discriminant

\textbf{divergenssi} divergence$_1$

\textbf{diversiteetti-indeksi} index of diversity

\textbf{do-laskenta} do-calculus

\textbf{do-operaattori} do-operator

\textbf{duaalilause} dual theorem

\textbf{duaalisuus} duality

\textbf{dynaaminen kiintiöinti} dynamic treatment allocation

\textbf{dynaaminen ohjelmointi} dynamic programming, dynamic optimization

\textbf{dynaaminen optimointi} dynamic optimization

\textbf{dynaaminen populaatio} dynamic population, open population

\bigletter

\textbf{\textit{E}-optimaalisuus} $E$-optimality

\textbf{editointisääntö} edit rule

\textbf{edustava otos} representative sample

\textbf{edustavuus} representativeness

\textbf{ehdokasjakauma} candidate distribution, proposal distribution

\textbf{ehdollinen autoregressio} conditional autoregression

\textbf{ehdollinen jakauma} conditional distribution

\textbf{ehdollinen odotusarvo} conditional expectation

\textbf{ehdollinen riippumattomuus} con\-ditional independence

\textbf{ehdollinen tiheysfunktio} conditional density function

\textbf{ehdollinen todennäköisyys} conditional probability

\textbf{ehdollinen uskottavuus} conditional likelihood

\textbf{ehdollinen varianssi} conditional variance

\textbf{ehdollistettu sirontakuvio} conditioning plot, coplot

\textbf{ehdotusjakauma} proposal distribution, candidate distribution

\textbf{ehkäisykoe} prevention trial

\textbf{ei-merkitsevä} nonsignificant

\textbf{ei-negatiivisesti definiitti} nonnegative definite

\textbf{ei-normaalinen} non-normal

\textbf{ei-satunnaisesti puuttuva} missing not at random

\textbf{ekologinen harha} ecological fallacy, ecological bias

\textbf{ekologinen korrelaatio} ecological correlation

\textbf{ekologinen tutkimus} ecological study, aggregate-level study

\textbf{ekologinen virhepäätelmä} ecological fallacy

\textbf{ekonometria} econometrics

\textbf{ekonometrikko} econometrician

\textbf{eksakti testi} exact test

\textbf{eksogeeninen muuttuja} exogenous variable

\textbf{eksogeenisuus} exogeneity

\textbf{eksponentiaalinen kasvu} exponential growth

\textbf{eksponentiaalinen trendi} exponential trend

\textbf{eksponenttijakauma} exponential distribution

\textbf{eksponenttinen tasoitus} exponential smoothing

\textbf{eksponenttinen trendi} exponential trend

\textbf{eksponenttiperhe} exponential family

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: search for "grid typesetting" (it's not so easy with tex, but loads of discussion on this site and elsewhere) but for your case it should be simpler,  get rid of the scalebox (almost always better to chose a font size rather than scale) then just arrange that the the total space is an exaxt multiple of the normal text baselineskip, so the big letter heading takes (say) 4 lines but then alignment is automatic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't get this. I made a macro like {\vspace{9.8mm} ...something here... \vspace{3mm}}, but it makes a slightly different space after "something" in different places. The difference is just a millimeter or so.

Comment: that space will not change but there may be other, stretchy, space added at the same point, section headings, lists, equations, paragraphs, all have stretch space around them by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, but the next paragraphs are just `\textbf{\textit{D}-optimaalisuus} $D$-optimality` and `\textbf{\textit{E}-optimaalisuus} $E$-optimality`.

Comment: as I say paragraphs have stretch space by default. the default parskip is  `\parskip=0pt plus 1pt`  so if you have `\flushbottom` (which you should not have for grid setting, then paragraphs will stretch apart if needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. So I changed `\parskip` to be `6.0pt` instead of `\medskipamount`. What else produces strech spaces? There is no `\flushbottom` in my .tex, but I don't know if `multicol` puts it in by default.

Comment: almost _all_ spacing added by tex is stretch by default, the standard classes are not set up for grid typesetting, you need to set spacing around headings, lists, math, etc to fixed values. As always if you provided a test document someone would debug it, without any code only general hints are possible

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I added an example to the question. I was not able to make a two-page long example.